# Merge Arrays into Object gives undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, lodash

I have a question regarding merging two arrays into a JSON object.

I receive an object from an API, the object contains an array of objects (columns) and an array of arrays (data).

I have implemented the following using zipObject from lodash to try and merge the columns and the data and create JSON objects using columns and the data.

```js
  function prepareTable() {
    let columns = apiData.columns
    let array = columns.map(function (obj) {
      return obj.title
    })
    const tableObject = apiData.data.map(datum => {
      _.zipObject(array, datum)
    })

    console.log(tableObject)
  }
```

When I do console.log for apiData.data or columns I can see all the data and also the array as 1 array with 18 elements:
[image]

However when I print the tableObject in console it returns undefined.
[image]

When I do console.log(typeof datum) for the code above I get 719 object types. I think this is the issue as zipObject receives two arrays as arguments, one for props and one for values.

I do not understand why when I map over an array of arrays I get object as type for each mapped item. I would expect array.

Anyone know where the issue might be and how to fix it?

Comment: You're not returning anything in your `.map()` function, so `undefined` is implicitly returned instead. Do `return _.zipObject(array, datum)` instead.

Comment: yeah, that did the trick. Thanks a lot, Terry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change to :

```
    const tableObject = apiData.data.map(datum =>  _.zipObject(array, datum))
```